# Can not find type or namespace in Visual Studio 2008, but the .dll is clearly included in the project, C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to open an old project in Visual Studio 2008, but I can not find how to properly get access to 'MainForm', which the application requires.

The compile error says the following: 
The type or namespace name 'MainForm' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have included System.Windows.Forms in the References, and added it with "using...", which according to what I could read online, is where 'MainForm' resides. Still no luck, the version of System.Windows.Forms I have does not seem to contain 'MainForm', and I can not import any other System.Windows.Forms.dll file than the one I have (it will throw and error that says that it can't find the file, basically).

Answers to relevant questions:

I do not surely know the .dot-net version the project was created in, but my best guess is 3.5. I found the following snippet in the .sln-file:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
# Visual Studio 2008
```

I can not open the program in a newer version of Visual studio since it throws up a myriad of errors which I can not resolve.

Comment: What is the project .net version?

Comment: Why not open with a new version of VS?

Comment: IIRC MainForm is the name that is usually given to your ... main form if you use the template to setup a WinForms project - so it's part of the project itself, not part of the framework.

Comment: James Gaunt: Hm, interesting.

Comment: As usual, if we use the old version of vs to open app developed by new version of vs, we may meet some errors. Therefore, first, I suggest that you can use new version of vs. Second, I recommend that you create the same dll in vs2008.